# Populate data in Jquery tabs from html pages onclick

Tags: jquery, html

I have many html pages (x.html, y.html). I am using jquery ui tabs.

how can i populate the data in each html pages in specific tab when click on a related button.

for example:

- clicking on button 'x' will populate data in x.html in x tab.
- clicking on button 'y' will populate data in x.html in y tab.

Here is the code i am using:

```
    <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">X</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Y</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p></p>
  </div>
    <p></p>
</div>
<script>
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
      $("#tabs-1").html(x.html);
      $("#tabs-2").html(y.html);
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function () {
      $("#tabs-1").html(z.html);
      $("#tabs-2").html(m.html);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show us some code and we can help you.

Comment: most tabs plugins have ajax content options...  for example jQueryUI tabs  http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax. If you want external buttons need to provide more details and provide html

Comment: Thanks, using ajax fixed half of the problem. the other half is:
I am using jquery ui accordion which has (btn1,btn2,etc)

tabs1 has tabs-1,tabs2,etc...
tabs2 has tabs-1,tabs2,etc...

 I need to have the following:

onClick (btn1) -> load(tabs1);
onClick (btn2) -> load(tabs2);